# C++ for each loop with mutating vector

Tags: c++, foreach, iterator

I just had a quick question about C++. If someone else has already asked this please let me know and I'll remove it as a duplicate.

My question is essentially, what is the behavior of a for each loop if you are changing the vector as you iterate. For example:

```
int main() {
    // your code goes here
    std::vector<char> v;
    for(char i = 'a'; i <= 'f'; i++) {
        v.push_back(i);
    }
    // v is {a, b, c, d, e, f}
    char c = 'A';
    for(const auto &elem : v) {
        cout << elem << ", ";
        v.push_back(c++);     // appending 'A', 'B', 'C', ...
    }
    cout << endl;
    // outputs: "a, b, c, , , ,"  (note there isn't a ... here, the loop stops).


    // Just printing normally now
    cout << "--------" << endl;
    for(const auto &elem : v) {
        cout << elem << ", ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    // outputs: a, b, c, d, e, f, A, B, C, D, E, F,
    return 0;
}
```

Could anyone potentially explain this behavior? I know the for each above is equivalent to the code below but that doesn't seem to make things any clearer.

```
for (auto __begin = v.begin(), __end = v.end();
    __begin != __end; ++__begin) {
    auto elem =  *__begin;
    cout << elem << ", ";
    v.push_back(c++);           // appending 'A', 'B', 'C', ...
}
cout << endl;
```

## Update:

This problem seems to be caused by the vector resizing which invalidates the iterators. Calling a `v.reserve(20)` after creating the vector fixes this and outputs: `a, b, c, d, e, f,` in the second floor loop.

Comment: Well, I suppose that when you call push_back, the value that v.end() increases by 1, and this is how it doesn't stop. For more information you can see the [end](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/end/) and [push_back](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) links.

Comment: @Thanasis But it does stop. I see how what I wrote might be confusing but it prints exactly "a, b, c, , , ,".

Comment: Mutating the vector while iterating it is fairly dangerous. In my system i.e. OSX, it does NOT output "a,b,c, , , ," it outputs "a,b,c,d,e,f," I guess how C++ handles this really depends on implementations. What system are you using?

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: @Tuan333 `g++ -std=c++11 -g  program.cpp` are the compiler settings I used on a Linux 64 bit machine.

Comment: do a reserve on the vector so it doesn't have to reallocate.

Comment: Eyyy, the msvc run time lib has actually asserted the iterator, finally they get something right!!!

Comment: @EvilTeach That makes sense and it does work. So it's just the resizing that basically messes up the iterators.

Comment: @gowrath.  Yep.  Hence Kennys answer is correct.  As a general rule if you know how big your vector is going to be, reserve it to that size.  It can save ya a crapton of malloc/free/construct/destruct calls that happen behind the scene.   If you can't do that, then you have to be careful not to invalidate your accessors.   Vector is free to move the underlying memory any time it wants to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the documentation for std::vector::push_back states

If the new size() is greater than capacity() then all iterators and references (including the past-the-end iterator) are invalidated. Otherwise only the past-the-end iterator is invalidated.

When the for loop increments, it compares the new iterator position to v.end() and probably goes into UB, probably some segfault or exception.

Comment: That's interesting. So in theory, if I make vector large enough initially so that  it doesn't need to resize, then this should print correctly.

Comment: No, it will still try to look at the end iterator every time you increment, in order to test the end of loop condition, and it can't do that, because end was invalidated.

Comment: I mean using reserve or for example calling `v.push_back('0')` 20 times and then `v.pop_back()` 20 times before the second for loop. This would push the capacity higher than the size when we go through the second loop.

Comment: Oh, you mean so that it only invalidates the iterator you need, and crashes anyway?

Comment: @gowarth in a ranged for or a for_each you should never change the size of the array.  Even if the size is always less then the capacity you brake the end iterator.

Comment: It actually "appears" to work in release mode on some compilers, but that is meaningless. It is undefined behavior because the for loop's terminate condition must look at the already invalidated end iterator after each loop.

Comment: @Nathan Oliver You are correct but in this case the initial end iterator is saved in __end so doesn't that bypass that issue?